# IJavaObject is included in multiple explicitly implemented interface types error using F#

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

Trying to add Google Drive support using '[Google Play Services - Drive](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleplayservices-drive/true)' in my Android F# project. But when implementing `GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener` interface, I receive the following message '*The interface IJavaObject' is included in multiple explicitly implemented interface types. Add an explicit implementation of this interface*'.

Here is an image of an error[image]

How to implement it?

Comment: Same way you implemented the other interfaces?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes, it was the first thing I did, something like
`type GDriveApi () =
    interface Android.Runtime.IJavaObject with 
        member this.Handle = ???`

but it expects from me to return `nativeint`. Also, from the official docs it says [never implement this interface yourself](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Runtime.IJavaObject/). The last suggestion is to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`, but this still not the solution in my case, because `IOnConnectionFailedListener` still expects 'IJavaObject' to be implemented (F# supports only explicit interfaces)

Comment: If you inherit from `JavaObject`, you can implement the interface by delegating each method to the base class.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type GDriveApi () =
    inherit Java.Lang.Object ()
    interface Android.Runtime.IJavaObject with 
        member this.Handle = base.Handle
    interface GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener with
        member this.OnConnectionFailed result = ()
    interface GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks with
        member this.OnConnectionSuspended cause = ()
        member this.OnConnected bundle = ()
```